# Angular2 Physics animation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, animation

I'm looking to perform some physics animations and have the animation carried out on a set of DOM elements.  Not canvas.  **Very important:  Not canvas.**

I have it working, but the performance is slower than I anticipated even considering how expensive DOM manipulations are.  It borders on unusable if you have more than a few components on the page at a time even if you adjust the interval to be less frequent.

I'm wondering if there is a simpler or more performant way while keeping things within Angular.  Maybe a way to skip the Angular rendering of the zone altogether?  Doing it vanilla without utilizing Angular bindings and such is *way* more performant so I'm wondering if I'm just doing the Angular portion wrong, or if I should break these sections free of Angular.  I thought Zones were supposed to outperform global manipulation though...?

Example code to wiggle something across the screen (the real animations are more complicated but follow this exact technique):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'thingy,[thingy]',
    template: `<div #container [ngStyle]="getStyle()"><ng-content></ng-content></div>`
})


export class Thingy implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private _x:number = 0;
    private _y:number = 0;
    private _interval:any;
    private _style:CSSStyleDeclaration = {
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        position: absolute
    };

    constructor(){}

    ngOnInit() {
        this._interval = setInterval(() => {
            this._x++;
            this._y = Math.sin(this._x);

            this._style.left = this._x + "px";
            this._style.top = this._y + "px";
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        clearInterval(this._interval); // because it continues ticking after destroy
    }

    getStyle():CSSStyleDeclaration {
        return this._style; // in angular1 it was bad joojoo to return a new object each time so i avoid doing so here too
    }
}
```

I've optimized this approach as much as I know how.  I think the built-in animation metadata solution could handle most of the scenarios but I haven't tried because a) I can't imagine how adding more abstraction increases performance and b) these animations are not state transitions so it doesn't seem appropriate.

I've also tried using a template more like this but it doesn't seem to be much different:

```
<div [style.top.px]="_y" [style.left.px]="_x"><ng-content></ng-content></div>
```

Also, I've tried directly messing with the ElementRef but that certainly didn't help:

```
@ViewChild("container") container:ElementRef;
this._container.nativeElement.styles.top = this._y + "px";
```

If it is best to do this outside of Angular's control, is there any standard for that?  I can draw the DOM element with a Component and then dispatch a Window event to kickstart non-angular code...

Also of note:  I cannot start at point A and jump immediately to point B in order to let CSS transitions paint the animation. The animations are not predictable enough to transition/ease.  Unless theres a very clever solution, I don't see how it can be animated except for ticking through each step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the performance issue by using a global ticker instead of having each component responsible for its own.  The ticker is a simple Observable which each component subscribes to and unsubscribes from where it would otherwise have started and stopped its own interval.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observer, Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class TickerService {
    private _observer: Observer<number>;
    private _timer:any;
    public data$ = new Observable(observer => this._observer = observer).share();

    constructor() {
        this.data$ = new Observable(observer => {
            this._observer = observer;
        }).share();
    }

    public start():void {
        if(this._timer) { // not required...  just didn't want to have two going at once
            this.stop();
        }

        this._timer = setInterval(() => {
            this.tick();
        }, 30);
    }

    public stop():void {
        clearInterval(this._timer);
        this._timer = 0;
    }

    private tick():void {
        this._observer.next(new Date().getTime()); // the date part is irrelevant.  i just wanted to use it to track the performance lag between each tick
    }
}
```

Items can them react to it as such:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'thingy,[thingy]',
    template: `<div #container [ngStyle]="getStyle()"><ng-content></ng-content></div>`
})


export class Thingy implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private _x:number = 0;
    private _y:number = 0;
    private _subscription:Subscription;
    private _style:CSSStyleDeclaration = {
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        position: absolute
    };

    constructor(private _ticker:TickerService){}

    ngOnInit() {
        this._subscription = this._ticker.data$.subscribe(() => {
            this._x++;
            this._y = Math.sin(this._x);

            this._style.left = this._x + "px";
            this._style.top = this._y + "px";
        });
        this._ticker.start(); // even though every instance will call this, there's a guard in the TickerService to only allow one ticker to run
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this._subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    getStyle():CSSStyleDeclaration {
        return this._style;
    }
}
```

This small change took the performance for 5 Thingys from about 5fps to about 60fps.  I believe this to be because each Thingy spawned its own ticker, causing its own (blocking) digest/paint to run out of sequence with the others.  This caused Angular to digest each change individually, and a giant stack built up.  Instead of one tick with 5 updates to perform, it was performing 5 ticks with 1 update each.

So now, all changes are made and then executed within one digest/zone update.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried using the built-in Renderer `setElementStyle` in Angular 2 instead of applying styles through the ngStyle directive ?

Comment: I haven't tried the Renderer.  I'll try that (might be a couple of days) and update with what I find though.